# how .aspx page work and what happens when i send the request to .aspx page first time?

Tags: asp.net

I got stuck here and I want to know how they actually .aspx page work when I send the request for the .aspx page the first time how HTML comes to the browser and when I click on the button what happens behind how the .aspx page gets executed and I want to know does it really need to know this in detail? and how. Does the aspx.cs page work?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace sample1
{
    public partial class First : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Welcome");
        }
    }
}



<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="First.aspx.cs" Inherits="sample1.First" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this: [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178472(v=vs.100))

Understanding [Page.IsPostBack Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.ispostback?view=netframework-4.8) property is also important.

> Gets a value that indicates whether the page is being rendered for the first time or is being loaded in response to a postback.

To understand that better, put a breakpoint inside the code written below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        // excecutes on page load
    }
    else
    {
        // executes on button click
    }

}
```